# ssh log sent to email in Cygwin

Tags: ssh, email, smtp, cygwin, syslog-ng

I am using Cygwin in Windows 7. I am trying to make my syslog-ng daemon send a ssh log via email to me when ever someone tries to log into my computer. I tried using the code below (entered into `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` but the smtp driver is not recognized. Is there a way to get it to work?

```
filter f_ssh {
        program("sshd"); };

    destination d_email_notification {
        smtp(
            host("localhost") port(25)
            from("syslog notification" "syslog@localhost")
            reply_to("syslog" "syslog@localhost")
            to("User" "user@email.com")
            subject("[syslog notification]: ssh message")
            body("Syslog received:\n$MSG")
            );
    };

    log {
        source(s_local);
        filter(f_ssh);
        destination(d_email_notification);
    };
```

Comment: I have fail2ban sending me alerts and it requires postfix or another MTA to send. You might start by installing postfix in cygwin.